# PHP. Check if a couple [Key]=>[Value] already exists in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to check if an array like this:

```
(["1"] => "30/11/2001 00:00:00" ["302"] => "2001-12-01 00:00:00" ["522"] =>"01/12/2012 00:00:00" ["1"] => "30/11/2001 00:00:00" etc...)
```

already exists the value pair that I am going to add. If already exists, I want to do some things, otherwise I want to do other things.

How do I find in the array (like the array I wrote) if already exists one or more pairs of values "["key"] => ["value"] ??

Comment: Check if [the key exists](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-key-exists.php), if it does, check it's value.

Comment: Dear @GeraldSchneider, I have some keys equal to each other and some values equal to each other (even for the same key). How to?

Comment: An array cant have duplicate keys

Comment: Yes, @Dagon, my array does!

Comment: It can have multiple same values. Never keys. Writing to same key overwrites prevous value.

Comment: Not possible "*If multiple elements in the array declaration use the same key, only the last one will be used as all others are overwritten*"

Comment: Ok, so I need multidimensional array with numbers (like the id column in database) and then key and values? Because i make the array from database. And in the database there are many key and values equal to each other.

Comment: Seems like a new question

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$tested_key = '302';
$tested_value = '2001-12-01 00:00:00';


if(isset($your_data[$tested_key]) AND $your_data[$tested_key] === $tested_value ){
    echo 'This Key exists with this value';
}
```

Comment: Dear Gacek, i don't understand your code. If i make an array from database with "SELECT" (and I have many keys and values equal to each other) I need a multidimensional array with index numbers, like the id in the database? And how to check then if there are some "key"=>"value"?

Comment: My code is checking first, if key is defined, then if value is same as one you want.
We would need to see your whole code, and understand what you're trying to achieve.
My code is really basic and simple.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to tell you, you can't have duplicate keys on your array !

See PHP doc :

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-97

Comment: Thanks. I changed my array in another one with id before a small array with key=>value. Now i have the same problem unresolved. How to check if in an array (multidimensional, with the id before key=>value) I have at least one couple key=>value?

Comment: Sorry but I didn't want to critique, I just don't understand what he want to achieve.